# Passing data from one tableview to another tableview using segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am really struggling to pass data from SecondViewController to ActivityFormTableViewController.

get this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'MajorActivity''

Code for two classes follow:

Any help would be received with gratitude.

```
//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  LinkByActivity
//
//  Created by Jeremy Andrews on 2015/06/10.
// version update 23/06/2015
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Jeremy Andrews. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class  SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
    var catRet = XnYCategories.mainCats("main")
    var activityDictionary = [String : [String]]()
    var key1:String!
    @IBAction func ActivityMainCats(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return catRet.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = catRet[row]
        return cell

    }

    // MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        var row = indexPath.row
        let key1 = catRet[row]
        println(key1)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("MajorActivity", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
            if (segue.identifier == "MajorActivity") {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ActivityFormTableViewController;
            svc.key2 = key1
            println(key1)

            }
        }


    }

//
//  ActivityFormTableViewController.swift
//  LinkByActivity
//
//  Created by Jeremy Andrews on 2015/07/24.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Jeremy Andrews. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ActivityFormTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView2: UITableView!
    var key2:String!
    var catRet2 = XnYCategories.mainCats("Sport")

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell2"
    var activityDictionary = [String : [String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(key2)
        var catRet2 = XnYCategories.mainCats(key2)
        println(catRet2)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        //var catRet2 = XnYCategories.mainCats(key2)

        return catRet2.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = catRet2[row]
        return cell

    }

    // MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        var row = indexPath.row
        let activityKey = "CellNo_" + "famNam_" + key2
        activityDictionary = [activityKey: ["TheForm", "l1", "etc"]]
        //println(activityDictionary)

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a segue that exists that is named MajorActivity from SecondViewController to ActivityFormTableViewController? The error is saying that you do not. To create a segue you can control drag or right click from one view controller to another in storyboard, you give it a name by clicking on it and using the attributes inspector.

Comment: just tried running  again with the following error:

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1067cb670) to 'LinkByActivity.ActivityFormTableViewController' (0x104f30ab0).
(lldb) \

Comment: I have segue on the storyboard with the name MajorActivity\

Comment: I understand, you need to create a UINavigationController in your prepare for segue, then assign your target view controller as it's top view controller and set properties on that, I"ll put up an answer with a quick example

Comment: storyboard as follows:

Comment: storyboard as follows tableview -> navigation controller -> tableview

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UINavigationController in your prepareForSegue method because it appears as that's what you have on your storyboard. Then you need to create an instance of the controller that you want the navigation controller to show and assign your properties to that.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "MajorActivity") {

        let activityFormNavController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

        let svc = activityFormNavController.topViewController as! ActivityFormTableViewController
        svc.key2 = key1
        println(key1)

        }
    }
```

**Storyboard Example:**

[image]

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var someString : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func fireSegueBttnTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    // set my local instance variable to some value to pass

    someString = "Stack Overflow Is Great!"

    performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "next" {

        // Create a UINavigationController instance first b/c that's where the segue goes

        let nextNavVc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

        // Create an instance of the top view controller belonging to the above crated navigation controller

        let nextVc = nextNavVc.topViewController as! SecondViewController

        // Assign the instance variable from this view controller to the variable on the view controller nextVc

        nextVc.passedString = someString

    }

}

}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

var passedString : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    if passedString != nil {

        outputLabel.text = passedString!
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

**Simulator Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much - I was stumped by the navigation controller between the two tables!
I am sure it will work - will try it out later. Thanks

Comment: That fixed the segue problem but I still get a nil on key1.
I will try using breakpoints to see why key1 changes to nil.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're setting the wrong "key 1" You're creating a new constant in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with "let key1 = " you need to use the key1 that's in scope of the prepareForSegueMethod

Comment: Oops will have puzzle this one out - I have the following code - but can't see where I have gone wrong

Comment: You just need to assign the let key1 value to the key1 that's present in your prepareForSegue method

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
  var row = indexPath.row
  let key1 = catRet[row]
  println(row)
  println(key1)
  performSegueWithIdentifier("MajorActivity", sender: self)
 }

Comment: and
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
  if (segue.identifier == "MajorActivity") {
   let activityFormNavController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
   let svc = activityFormNavController.topViewController as! ActivityFormTableViewController
   println(key1)
   svc.key2 = key1
   println(svc.key2)
   
  }
 }

Comment: just change "let key1" to "key1" in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath - you need to learn about the scopes of  your variables.

Comment: Thanks - just saw your full comment.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the SecondViewController issue - still not getting the value over to ActivityFormTableViewController. You are right I need to sort out the scopes  concept in my mind..

Comment: If you are assigning the correct key1 you should see it in your print statement. There's not a lot of mystery surround scopes, anything declared inside a set of { } can not be accessed outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I now get the correct value for key1 and key2 in SecondViewController.swift but key2 becomes nil in ActivityFormTableViewController.swift so clearly I have got something wrong in this class. Just can't see what.

Comment: Still can't find by mistake - I am sure its probably a simple oversight.

Comment: I will update my answer with a more thorough code example